# Get value from listBox using List

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listbox

I am using a `ListBox` and the data is a class:

```
private class Duration
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

I bind the class in this way:

```
var durations = new List<Duration>() 
  {
    new Duration() { Value = 5, Label = "5 minutes" }, 
    new Duration() { Value = 10, Label = "10 minutes" }, 
    new Duration() { Value = 15, Label = "15 minutes" }, 
    new Duration() { Value = 30, Label = "30 minutes" }, 
    new Duration() { Value = 45, Label = "45 minutes" }, 
    new Duration() { Value = 60, Label = "1 hour" }, 
    new Duration() { Value = 90, Label = "1 hour and half" } 
  };
this.listTime.DataSource = durations;
this.listTime.DisplayMember = "Label";
this.listTime.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Everything works fine and the labels are show.
When i go to read the selected value, I am not able to recover the value of the selected item.

I was expecting to be able to do this:

```
int value = listTime.SelectedItems[0].Value;
```

or at least this:

```
Duration value = listTime.SelectedItems[0];
```

but this gives me error, what I am doing wrong? How is the right way to get the value of the selected item on the `ListBox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (listTime.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    var item = listTime.SelectedItem as Duration;
    //or as suggested by 'Stu'
    var item = (Duration)listTime.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(item.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: `var item = (Duration) listTime.SelectedItem`

Comment: No biggie here. On fail of the cast, in my case null is returned, in your case an exception is thrown. In both cases this has to be caught...

Comment: In your example, it would crash on the next line anyway, so the less efficient cast is wasteful.

Comment: Yes, like I said. In your case the MessageBox will never be shown as an exception will be thrown. Therefore these cases have to be caught and taken care of, whether using my or your cast.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Listbox this code is Ok:

```
listTime.Items[0].Value
```